# Get difference between two dates programatically

Tags: 8, datetime

**In summary:**

On a Drupal 8 project, i am trying to programatically get the difference between two different times (current time - Node creation time)

**Use case:**

I have "nodeabc" already available on the site.

When a specific webform is submitted and by using a custom webform handler, I want to get the **difference in minutes** between **current time** and **nodeabc creation time**.

Say **nodeabc** was created on: **24/06/2019 08:00 AM** and the webform is being submitted on: **24/06/2019 07:00 PM**, so the difference between both times will be: **660** minutes.

I have already loaded the node by its nid but how to continue in achieving the above ?

**UPDATE #1:**

From @Prestosaurus answer, I did the below in my webform custom handler php file:

```
$nid = '125';
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);

$creationtime = $node->getCreatedTime();

// Get "Time Diff Since" creation time.
$creationsince = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->formatTimeDiffSince($creationtime);
```

the above code returned: `7 hours 30 minutes` which is good but then I added the below code to the above one:

```
$totalamount = $creationsince * 5000;
```

But while testing it returns a php error `InvalidArgumentException: $string ("35000") must be a string.`

I believe I am half way to the answer but still need to convert the `$creationsince` value to `450` minutes instead of `7 hours 30 minutes`.

Is that doable ?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a human-readable difference like "11 hours ago"? Or do you want a numeric value in seconds like "39600"?

Comment: @aaronbauman actually i need both ! (1) i want a human-readable difference like "7 hours 30 minutes" so i can save the value in a text box field for users to read it. (2) i want also a numeric value **in hours** like 7.6 so i can multiply this value (Ex: 7.6) by another numeric value and save the results in another text box... in other words, say that a user get pay 5$ for 1 working hour, when the user will work from **24/06/2019 08:00 AM** until **24/06/2019 07:15 PM** so he worked *11 hours 15 minutes* which means **11.25** hours and so `11.25 × 5 = 90$`

Comment: $creationsince is a string. Try: `$minutesPassed = round(($submission->completed->value - $createdTimestamp)/60) . ' minutes';`. There may be D8 methods for this, but I have not found them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a node, `$node`:

```
$diffSeconds = time() - $node->getCreatedTime();
$diffHours = (($delta_seconds / 60.0) / 60.0);
$formattedTimeDiff = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')
  ->formatTimeDiffSince($node->getCreatedTime());
```

`$diffSeconds` is the number of seconds between node creation time and now.

Thus `$diffHours` is the number of hours (float) between node creation time and now.

[`formatTimeDiffSince()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Datetime!DateFormatter.php/function/DateFormatter%3A%3AformatTimeDiffSince) converts this to a human readable value, e.g. "1 hour 15 minutes"

---

For the webform timestamps:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  $createdTimestamp = $variables['node']->getCreatedTime();

  $webform_submissions = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('webform_submission')
    ->loadByProperties([
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'entity_id' => $variables['node']->id(),
  ]);

  $submission_timestamps = [];
  $timeDiffs = [];
  $timeAgos = [];

  foreach ($webform_submissions as $submission) {
    $submission_timestamps[] = $submission->completed->value;
    $timeDiffs[] = $submission->completed->value - $createdTimestamp;
    $timeAgos[] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')
      ->formatTimeDiffSince($submission->completed->value);
  }

}
```

Webform timestamps cover `->created`, `->completed`, and `->changed`.

Comment: Can you please explain how to make the `current time` not static ?

Comment: The above is a handy D8 method, but it sounds like you want to compare two static time stamps. If I understand correctly, and this will ultimately be shown in node template, I believe you just need the node created date and the associate webform submission date. These would both be acquired in hook_preprocess_node I would assume. After that sounds like standard manipulation with math on the time values.

Comment: Answer has been edited. Again, for the human readable created against submission time, will need a little more leg work, but that’s just formatting.

Comment: please see my edit to the question (**Update #1**), I believe i am half way to the answer!